# Upload is not producing any results

Tags: php, file-upload

I have made this script for uploading remote files but the file is not uploaded to server and  the database for `var1` remains empty. Here is  my code.

HTML:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form1" method="post" action="">
    <p><label>Upload songs</label>      
    <input type="text" name="song"><input type="submit" value="Submit" class="button"></p>
</form>
```

PHP:

```
$uri = copy1_file($_POST['song']);
$story['v1'] = $uri;

        $url = $_POST['song'];
    $file = fopen ($url, "rb");
    if ($file) {
        $newf = fopen ($uri, "wb");
        if ($newf) {
            while(!feof($file)) {
                fwrite($newf, fread($file, 1024 * 8 ), 1024 * 8 );
            }
        }
    }
    if ($file) {
        fclose($file);
    }
    if ($newf) {
        fclose($newf);
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I have checked the error log but nothing is coming. Where I am doing a mistake?

Comment: If you want to receive a URL from user,change `type="file"` to `type="text"`.

Comment: @death sorry its type="text" only type=file will call for browse optin from users computer

Comment: @payal `type="file"` opens a dialog box which prompts user to select a FILE FROM USERS COMPUTER, which you don't want, as explained in the comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read up on [PHP File Uploads](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php).

Try this to debug your script:

```
var_dump($_FILES);
```

Do you see anything?

**EDIT:** Okay, I see you more clearly defined "remote files." You have to use a "text" input to receive the URL. How did you get around the standard file selection dialog?

It looks like your code will work as-is if you just change the `<input/>` type to "text".

**EDIT 2:** I noticed you updated your post to have `<input type="text"/>` so you already have a URL making it through to your script. Check to see if your host has [allow_url_fopen](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) enabled. If not, your URL will not be retrieved by `fopen()`. You will have to use `cURL` instead.

**EDIT 3:** Could it be that your `copy1_file` function never actually returns the uri? There are a lot of errors in the code in that function. Ex: `copy1_file` is receiving a url, why does it have `$file['name']` at the top? And later reference `$_POST` directly? There are more errors. Check it closely and correct them, then it should work fine since you say `fopen(url)` is known to work with your host.

Comment: sorry i have wriitten type=file but it was text my host allows fopen but its not working i checked. thanks for guiding.there is no limitation from host as i have used fopen several times without any issues

Comment: I made some more suggestions. There are many coding errors in your `copy1_file` function.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `$_FILES` array to access uploaded files instead of `$_POST`

here is the sample code for handling file uploads:

```
$pathToSaveFile = '...'; // this is the file path where the uploaded file should be saved
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['song']['tmp_name'], $pathToSaveFile);
```

**UPDATE**

if you need just to upload a file by URL then you don't need `<input type="file">`, just use simple `<input type="text">` and after user inserts URL and submits, you can use [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) and [file_put_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) functions:

```
file_put_contents($pathToSavePath, file_get_contents($_POST['song']));
```

to be able to use these functions to download remote files, make sure that `allow_url_fopen` option of PHP is set to TRUE

Comment: @payal what does it mean "remote url not from user's computer"?

Comment: remote files means just give the url and it will upload not from users computer

Comment: can you please advise in my script what is the problem